# How to find out which resources are unused in my android application?

Tags: android

How to find out which resources (Like drawable, layout etc.) are unused in my android application? I am sure some of the resource is not used but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: yoou can enable a lint warning for the same

Comment: @Raghunandan: How to add a lint warning for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

This is for eclipse. I am sure other ide's may also support the same.

Here's the list of all lint checks

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Open Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking. Scroll down and check for unused resources. Change the severity as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.The ide which I use is Intellij,but I think it is simliar as eclipse.The problem is,in the code editor,the ide tell me some unused variable which really used in some circumstance, and,in the project view,it don't tell me which file I don't use.Maybe I'll try eclipse later.Thank you very much

Comment: @MarshalChen configure lint in itellij ide. I am not sure how coz ihave not use that ide. but you can configure the same and check again

Comment: @Raghunandan There is a option which called 'unused resources' in 'Android Hint',but it is only available for analyze|Inspect Code.And I'm trying eclipse now

Comment: @MarshalChen i have not used itellij ide . but for eclipse you can check the docs in the first link in my post. there is topic on how to tcreate custom lint check also

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes,I find it runs great.And could you tell me how to delete the unused resource automatically?

Comment: @MarshalChen you can configure the severity and also disable the warning as you wish. check the snap shot  check the button ignore and ignore all

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm sorry but what I want is to really delete the unused resource,not only ignore the warnings

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) is the manual of Lint.

Also you can check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/) library.

Andround Unused Resources is a Java application that will scan your project for unused resources. Unused resources needlessly take up space, increase the build time, and clutter the IDE's autocomplete list.

To use it, ensure your working directory is the root of your Android project, and run:

```
java -jar AndroidUnusedResources.jar
```

Comment: Thank you.But in fact I have already tried this jar,but it can't find any unused resource.So i wonder if I use it for a wrong way or it can't found the relation of some resource

Comment: @MarshalChen which ide do you use

Comment: @Raghunandan Intellij Idea